# WPF, update TextBlock when CheckBox checked

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `TreeView` where each item has a checkbox.  I want a `TextBlock` to be updated whenever an item is checked or unchecked in the `TreeView`.  The `TextBlock`'s `Text` should be bound to the `CheckedVersions` property on my `DataContext` so that when I read the `CheckedVersions` property, it gives me a string representing all the checked items in the `TreeView`.  The checked items should be represented in a semicolon-separated string.  What would be the best way to do this?  I have the following XAML:

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="XmlData/Versions.xml" XPath="//*[count(*)=0]"
                 x:Key="versionsXml"
                 IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" IsAsynchronous="False" />
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="versionTemplate">
    <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"
              Content="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneTime}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<TreeView x:Name="trv_version"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Versions, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource versionTemplate}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="txb_version" Text="{Binding Path=CheckedVersions}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Each item in my `TreeView` is an instance of my `VersionViewModel` class, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and notifies when the `IsChecked` property changes.  It seems like I should be able to hook into that so that when `IsChecked` changes on a `VersionViewModel` instance in the `TreeView`, `CheckedVersions` updates.  Maybe if I set `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `Text` binding in the `TextBlock`?  What should I set it to, though?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your tree view model should "know" all the VersionViewModels and then all you need to do is register to the propertychanged event and set the "CheckedVersions" property according to the change.

something like that:

```
public class treeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<VersionViewModel> CurrentVersionViewModel { get; protected set; }

    public void AddNewVersionViewModel(VersionViewModel vvm)
    {
        CurrentVersionViewModel.Add(vvm);
        vvm.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(
            (obj,propEventArgs) => 
                {
                if (propEventArgs.PropertyName=="IsChecked")
                {
                // CheckedVersions change logic according to the new value (this is just the concept)
                    CheckedVersions += (obj as VersionViewModel).IsChecked;
                }
                }
            );
    }

    public string CheckedVersions { get { return _CheckedVersions; } set { _CheckedVersions = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CheckedVersions"); } }
    private string _CheckedVersions;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class VersionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```